# Find color distance in a series of images with different color temperatures

Tags: r, image-processing

I have a dataset of images and want to find the color distance of a color compared to a reference color. Unfortunately, the images were taken at different time points under different light conditions.

To illustrate my problem, let's have a look at an example image given by the imager package and create a duplicate with some different (s?)RGB values:

```
library(imager)

boats2 <- as.data.frame(boats)

boats2[which(boats2$cc == 1),"value"] <- boats2[which(boats2$cc == 1),"value"] * 1.05
boats2[which(boats2$cc == 2),"value"] <- boats2[which(boats2$cc == 2),"value"] * 0.99
boats2[which(boats2$cc == 3),"value"] <- boats2[which(boats2$cc == 3),"value"] * 0.99

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(boats)
plot(as.cimg(boats2))
```

Let's say I wanted to compare the yellow part of the sails with a reference yellow to find out which one is closer to the reference.

To proceed, I was thinking about

1. calculating an "average white" by finding the pixel with the highest RGB values in each image and averaging them and
2. using the average RGB values as conversion factor for all other images.

However, is white balancing actually necessary if I am interested in a color difference? Thinking about the example images, does it make sense to apply a white balance before determination of the color difference or is another approach better?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no way around doing some form of white balance. That's how experiments work: If there's a factor you cannot keep constant (or vary in a controlled manner), you need to somehow account for the variability. If taking the pictures in a well-lit studio was not an option, including a color calibration chart in each shot would have been the next best thing to try. Or at least a neutral grey card. You need some form of reference point - do you have anything in your images that is always the same?

Comment: You accurately described why it makes sense to consult the guy who is supposed to do data analysis BEFORE running the experiment ;) I got control images that were taken at the same time under the same conditions as the experimental ones. The question is thus still how to calculate an “average white”, for instance of the example pictures, and apply it to the other images. Is RGB the right colorspace for this?

Comment: Oh dear, I hear ya ... I'm still struggling a bit to fully grasp your experimental design, though - could you elaborate a bit on the above? What is the scale of the whole thing - do you need to script it or could you do some things semi-manually in something like Darktable/Lightroom? It seems like step 1 would be to align the control images against each other so they all agree on what is neutral grey. Record the adjustments necessary to reach that point per control image and apply the same adjustment to the corresponding experimental ones. Then compare across batches, if that's what you want?

Comment: I got six groups (control, 5x treatment) with images taken at four timepoints and 60 images per timepoint, summing up to 6 x 4 x 60 = 1440 images in total. 
You describe exactly what I was thinking of, but what would be the right colourspace and equations for this? Would it work in RGB? Does it make more sense to go for a reference white, e.g. D65 and, if yes, how to adjust the images according to the reference white?

Answer (score 0):

This is taking much more space than the comments offer, so I guess I'll put this here for further discussion.

First of all: I have close to 0 experience in the scientific side of image processing, this is mostly the photographer part of my brain working here. Some general thougts:

- White balance comes as early in the processing pipeline as possible, basically straight after de-mosaicing. If you have [RAW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format) files, you absolutely want to use these as opposed to out-of-camera JPGs.
- I don't see why some form of RGB-based wouldn't work, but I can't advise on the differences of sRGB vs. AdobeRGB vs. other flavors. Once you're done with the pre-processing/calibration, something like HSL might indeed be a smart solution for the actual analysis.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about equations until I really had to: 4 different lighting scenarios = 4 batches feels like something best handled through batch-processing in photography software. Since you're making global adjustments, I'd recommend a digital darkroom (like Darktable (FOSS), Adobe Lightroom, Rawtherapee (FOSS)) over the likes of Photoshop. They are great for RAW files but work on JPG too.

So, here's what I'd try:

1. Load all your images into your catalog/film roll/whatever your software calls it.
2. Open one of the reference images.
3. Identify something that should be neutral grey and use that as your reference area for a spot white balance. Could also use a small area, such as a black letter printed on a white object. (If your reference images are largely identical apart from the lighting, it may be sufficient to just apply auto white balance to the whole image). [For example like this in Darktable (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dfm1vmk9KDE)
4. If brightness varies between lighting situations too: Find something in the image that you can call "black" and "white" and use those as reference for setting your brightness levels.
5. Save and exit.
6. Copy the processing settings from the reference images to the corresponding experiment images. *This is the main reason why I'm suggesting to give this approach a try: it makes it very easy to process a batch of images in exactly the same way as a previously processed reference image.* [For example like this in Darktable (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04yHYBotT00)
7. Repeat 2.-6. with the other 3 reference images, using the same reference points/areas. They should hopefully look reasonably similar now.
8. Batch-export all images.

That's all assuming you do *not* have a proper color chart in your reference images. If you do have one, there's much more you can do.

N.B.: I'm mentioning Darktable a lot because that's what I use. I should warn that it is a bit of a nerd's choice: incredibly powerful with lots of options available to you, but a bit overwhelming at first. The workflow above only uses some of the most basic tools that are available in *any* virtual darkroom type software.

Comment: As much as I do love to do as much as possible in R, sometimes it's better to use a more specialized tool. But if someone can do this in R, I'd love to see that!